# fixing a div horizontally not vertically

Tags: css, scroll

Hello i want some help i want to fix a div horizontally when i scroll left and right and it goes up and down when i scroll vertically just like the div that containt mvp and alpha1 in the gif thank you in advance.

i did try absolute but it goes in the wrong way fixed vertically and goes left and right

```
        <ng-container *ngFor="let r of getReleaseRows()">

            <div fxLayout="row">
                <div class="reee"> Release {{r?.id}}</div>

            </div>
            <hr>

.reee {
    position: absolute;
}
```

[image: okey]

Comment: where is your html and css ??

Comment: code is edited !